# Quickbooks Online Api SDK c# - Is there a way to create and update hidden custom field for bill with use api

Tags: c#, advanced-custom-fields, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We need to add service information like officeId for entities.

Or how we can use IntuitAnyType for set and get our service information. I tried to add xmlElement into IntuitAnyType, and then create bill, but when I try to get this bill, IntuitAnyType field (BillEx) was null. Also I tried to add NumberTypeCustomFieldDefinition and got Validation Exception was thrown.Details:Operation Could not find resource for relative : /v3/company/4620816365019493550/numbertypecustomfielddefinition of full path: https://c50.sandbox.qbo.intuit.com/qbo50/v3/company/xxxxxxxxxxx/numbertypecustomfielddefinition?minorversion=29&requestid=a52a148d0f6f4c3ab366f55ca7440525 is not supported..

```
var dataService = new DataService(_serviceContext);
var officeId= new QBO.NumberTypeCustomFieldDefinition()
{
     DefaultValue = 0,
     DefaultValueSpecified = true,
     Name = "OfficeId",
     Hidden = true,
     EntityType = QBO.objectNameEnumType.Bill.ToString(),
     Required = false
};
var createdCaseIdField = dataService.Add(caseId);
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to create and update hidden custom field for bill with use api

No. Custom fields can only be created via the UI, and they are visible in the UI.

This is all documented here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/create-custom-fields#enable-custom-fields

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe you know how I can get all fields for bill with use api? When I try to get bill Memo I get null for this field